# flutter run m1 with plugins fail pod and android emulator doesn't build

Tags: android, flutter, apple-m1

**I AM NOT ABLE TO DEVELOP FLUTTER APPS ON MacBook Air M1**

- when I run on android studio

```
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

- when I run on terminal running with rosseta it works and installs but the app itself is not working which I didn't expect

```
sibusisomahlangu@Masanas-MacBook-Air ios % flutter run              
Changing current working directory to:
/Users/sibusisomahlangu/StudioProjects/mr_foodie
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1 815ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5,8s
Xcode build done.                                           27,0s
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The
device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with
--host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: OS Error:
Connection refused, errno = 61, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 61587
This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
```

- It gets stuck here when running on android emulator and when I change it to x86_64 it fails, looking for a working solution slow or fast just working.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using vscode which now works on both android and IOS emulator, just have android studio for AVD than you are good to go.